How do I configure LXQt to show text the same size as Firefox and other applications?
I have a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04, and switched to LXQt using apt install task-lxqt-desktop. Now my 4K screen shows huge text for the LXQt applications (Qt applications?). I want the text to be similar in pixel size as the other applications like Firefox and the window titles.
What do I need to change to have them rendered similar to the firefox text?

(left == bad, right == good :) )
Changing DPI setting did not have any visible effect; changing QT_SCALE_FACTOR to 2 made it worse, and 0.5 broke my UI :) - note to self: don't go below 1.0).

You mention a release (22.04) and adding LXQt ; did you upgrade to a newer LXQt using Lubuntu backports? https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lxqt-1-4-arriving-at-a-lubuntu-backports-ppa-near-you/4670    Sorry I don't have/use 4K screens so haven't explore using scaling, but do recall reading scaling improved (but I forget when/why, LXQt was updated a number of times via backports PPA for jammy/22.04)

Running xrandr --dpi 96 "fixes" the display of text. Now I only need to figure out how to make that a permanent solution.
Edit: looks like adding a ~/.Xresources file with content
Xft.dpi: 96

Does it. Will see if it sticks during a couple of restarts.

Session settings (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html) is one way  (autostart tab)   Well done for solving your issue;  FYI: this link will represent the 22.04 manual only until 24.10 is released (it'll then become 24.04 manual which currently is the stable manual).
